# "Global" transaction for Sql Server or a workaround for missing transaction in API

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have an API for a desktop application. The API I must currently use and I can not change it.

This API, via internal code in the application, eventually inserts/updates data into an Sql Server (2014 in this particular case, but could be other versions also).

The issue is that the developers of the API did not use transactions. I can see live that one by one value is added and committed, and when inserting large amounts of data this of course takes ages.

Is there a functionality in Sql Server where I could ensure that all CRUD operations would have a transaction globally in a database?

Or is there a method for hijacking the connection(s) and starting a transaction from the outside?

Or any other workarounds?

I would like having to avoid reverse engineering the table structures as they have tendency to change a decent amount between versions.

Comment: Why would transactions make your inserts faster? If anything, it would slow them down.

Comment: If you cannot modify the client code at all I don't really see how this scenario could possibly be improved, aside from upgrading to SQL Server 2016+ and using an in-memory table (which will not eliminate the overhead of single inserts, but reduce it so much that it may become irrelevant). @DavidG: wrapping multiple inserts in a transaction cuts down on the time needed to wait for the (synchronous) transaction log writes to catch up, which the server must do before it can acknowledge the insert to the client. The difference can be quite dramatic. (Of course, bulk insert is even better.)

Comment: There's one more thing you can do if you can live with a decrease in reliability: you can use [delayed durability](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/logs/control-transaction-durability) (forced in this case) to cut down on the time needed to write to the transaction log by allowing SQL Server to defer it. Your mileage may vary -- I've yet to find scenarios where it really significantly speeds things up, as opposed to explicit transactions.